# Cummulative sum in report

Tags: sql

[image: Sample report]

Hello All,

I am working on a report where I am doing calculations:

Let's take the first line as an example. In the remaining prior column we have 15 and in the taken column we have 0.5, so in the remaining column, we have 14.5.

Now the issue is to use the result in the remaining field and transfer it to the next line in the remaining prior column. So instead of having 14 we should be having 14.5.

Has anyone worked on something similar and guide me on how to work on this? I really want to learn how to solve such an issue.

Comment: You should read about Database normalization first. This is a poor database design.

Comment: These are results from values in various tables. The attached screenshot is only a sample report with the column names I defined.

Comment: "Has anyone worked on something similar" Yes. "and guide me on how to work on this?" Don't do it in SQL - do it in your application layer or reporting layer. SQL is not designed to do "running totals" (or any other operations that depend on data in other rows of the result).

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI standard `lag()` function does exactly what you want.  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so I need to assume that you have some column -- which I will call `id` -- that identifies the ordering of the rows.

The syntax for `lag()` is:

```
select t.*, lag(Remaining) over (order by 1) as prevRemaining
from table t;
```

If you have a database that does not support the ANSI standard window functions, you can get the same effect with a subquery.  However, the syntax for that might vary slightly among databases.